# How do I get the value of a user-selected radio button in the controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am writing a simple survey app in Angularjs, and would like to capture the result of radio button selection and store the answers in an array inside the controller. I have an array of question objects, each with a body field and a choice field which consists of string values for choices. I am trying to bind the value of the selected radio button with the 'ng-model' attribute. I cannot seem to access this value from within the controller.

Here is the index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="estimatorApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js">    </script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="QuestionListCtrl">

    {{question}} <br/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="choice in questions[q_counter].choices">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="answer" ng-click="next()" \
                ng-value="name" name="answer"> {{choice}} <br/>
        </li>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the 'controller.js' file:

```
var estimatorApp = angular.module('estimatorApp', [])
estimatorApp.controller('QuestionListCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.questions = [
        {'body': 'What kind of app do you want to build?',
         'choices': ['iOS', 'Android', 'Mobile Web'] },
        {'body': 'Have you already started development?',
         'choices': ['yes', 'no'] }
    ];
    $scope.q_counter = 0;
    $scope.question = $scope.questions[$scope.q_counter]['body'];
    $scope.answers = []
    $scope.answer = ""

    $scope.next = function() {
        if ($scope.q_counter < $scope.questions.length-1) {
            console.log("answer: " + $scope.answer); // $scope.answer is undefined
            $scope.q_counter += 1;
            $scope.question = $scope.questions[$scope.q_counter]['body'];
        } else {
            console.log($scope.answers);
        }
    }

});
```

Once I am able to capture the result of an input, I will push it on the end of the $scope.answers array to store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `answers` array directly if you want.  You already have an index to use with `q_counter` so this is fairly straight forward.

The things I added were `ng-model="answers[q_counter]"` and setting the value with `value="{{choice}}"`.

Here is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pdgRgv?p=preview).

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('QuestionListCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.questions = [
        {'body': 'What kind of app do you want to build?',
         'choices': ['iOS', 'Android', 'Mobile Web'] },
        {'body': 'Have you already started development?',
         'choices': ['yes', 'no'] }
    ];
    $scope.q_counter = 0;
    $scope.question = $scope.questions[$scope.q_counter]['body'];
    $scope.answers = []
    $scope.answer = ""

    $scope.next = function() {
        if ($scope.q_counter < $scope.questions.length-1) {
            console.log($scope.answers); // $scope.answers is the full list of answers
            $scope.q_counter += 1;
            $scope.question = $scope.questions[$scope.q_counter]['body'];
        } else {
            console.log($scope.answers);
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="QuestionListCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>


    {{question}} <br/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="choice in questions[q_counter].choices">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="answers[q_counter]" ng-change="next()" value="{{choice}}" name="answer"> {{choice}} <br/>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```